# What's the maximum size of the memo in a LN payment request?

Tags: lightning-network, lncli, invoices

What is the maximum size of text held in the memo portion of a lightning network payment request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The memo field can hold 639 bytes of information.**

But how many characters? Let's assume utf8 (since lncli encodes the text in utf8)

utf8's characters are variable length, meaning some are larger than others.

From [stackoverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229225/5838056)

> The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte.
>
> The next 1,920 characters need two bytes to encode. This covers the
>   remainder of almost all Latin alphabets, and also Greek, Cyrillic,
>   Coptic, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac and Tāna alphabets, as well
>   as Combining Diacritical Marks.
>
> Three bytes are needed for characters in the rest of the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane, which contains virtually all characters in common
>   use[12] including most Chinese, Japanese and Korean [CJK] characters.
>
> Four bytes are needed for characters in the other planes of Unicode,
>   which include less common CJK characters, various historic scripts,
>   mathematical symbols, and emoji (pictographic symbols).

For the [US-ASCII character set](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) and onward:

639 bytes / (1 byte / 1 char) = 639 characters

639 bytes / (2 byte / 1 char) = 319 characters

639 bytes / (3 byte / 1 char) = 213 characters

639 bytes / (4 byte / 1 char) = 159 characters